# edit multiline code snippet in ipython

Tags: ipython

Is there a way to edit multiline code snippit in ipython?  Imagine I wrote the following code,

```
In [1]: fur i in xrange(10):
 ...:     print i
```

how can I change the *fur* to *for*?  My cursor does not want to go up.

Moreover, if I execute the code and press the *up* arrow, all my indentation disappear and the code is no more valid.

```
In [2]: fur i in xrange(10):
   print i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it does not remove the indentation, just make the code use different number of space for indentation. After executing, you can use Ctrl-a to go to the beginning of the line and edit fur to for.

Now try running the code and it will run ok.